# Java getAbsolutePath returning wrong path

Tags: java, eclipse

This likely a very simple solution, but I can not seem to find the proper setting to adjust it. I have a file, lets say `config.prop` that needs to get read in by my application. It is at relative path `./someFolder/config.prop` to my application. Whenever I try to get the absolute path of this, it returns a path that says it is in my eclipse folder, no my project.

```
String fileLocation = "./someFolder/config.prop"
File file = new File(fileLocation);
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

This will return `C:\eclipse-mars\.\someFolder\config.prop` where it really should return `C:\my\project\path\someFolder\config.prop`

I imagine this is some project setting that is super simple I am missing, but not sure where it may be in eclipse, I am not super familiar with eclipse.

Comment: It's using JVM instance's working dir, which is Eclipse's root. Is it necesary to use a relative path? Could be considered to use an environment variable?

Comment: @Alfabravo I mean a relative variable would be nicer.

Comment: @Alfabravo I meant that a relative path would be nicer, I didn't notice my wrong typing in time for the edit window

Comment: If you think there is a bug in the JRE, you are probably mistaken. So there is a bug in your code or your understanding.

Comment: @Raedwald Where am I implying that there is an error in the JRE? I was simply asking how to change the path that the JVM was using inside of eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working directory can be set on your Java Application Launch Configuration's **Arguments** tab. You can open the **Launch Configuration Dialog** from the menu bar via **Run**->**Run...**.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!